# Is there a way to move a remote controlled car built with Raspberry Pi 3 using speech recognition?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, raspberry-pi3

The python code below is the part which uses voice commands to control a remote controlled car built with Raspberry Pi 3 using Voice commands. But when I execute the code the car does not move according to the command given by the user. The car doesn't move at all.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

I tried running the code in sudo mode but it still does not move the car. The code below is enclosed in a while True: loop which ends only when a user says stop or quit. I have used speech_recognition module for speech recognition.

```
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Give a voice command like move forward")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    command = r.recognize_google(audio)
    try:
        print("Google Speech recognition thinks you said " + command)
        print("Moving "+command)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")  
    if "stop" or "quit" in command:
        stop()
        exit(0)
    if "left" in command:
        print("Left")
        left()
        time.sleep(button_delay)
    if "right" in command:
        print("Right")
        right()
        time.sleep(button_delay)
    if "forward" or "straight" in command:
        print("Forward")
        forward()
        time.sleep(button_delay)
    if "reverse" or "back" in command:
        print("Reverse")
        reverse()
        time.sleep(button_delay)
    stop()
```

When we run the program it should accept the voice command and check if the any of the terms like forward, left, right etc as mentioned in the if statement is present. If it's present it should execute the function inside the if statement which gives the Raspberry Pi 3 instruction to move the motors of the car accordingly.

For example, if we say move forward. It checks if the word forward is there in the command. And since its there it executes forward() function which tells the Raspberry Pi 3 to move the motors connected to the gpio ports to move which results in the RC Car moving forward. But it doesn't move forward.

Comment: It might be the issue with wires, the speech recognition code is ok.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the wire as I have already implemented the same using a keyboard instead of the speech recognition. And it works with keyboard inputs.